# Word 2007 VBA to insert text

Tags: vba, text, ms-word

I want to insert text with custom formatting, then change the font style back to what it was before the code was run.

```
Dim myText As String
Dim oldFont As Object
'Save old font    
Set oldFont = Selection.Font 

'Insert text with custom font
myText = "CUSTOM STRING"
Selection.Font.Name = "Comic Sans MS"
Selection.Font.Size = 26
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Selection.TypeText (myText)

'Revert font back to original
Set Selection.Font = oldFont
```

Can anyone explain a way to do what I'm looking for?

Edit: I should have been more specific. If I am typing text, I have a certain formatting that I am typing in that is shown on the Home Tab (eg. Comic Sans Ms, Size 22, Bold). When I insert text with the code, this changes the formatting that I am typing with, so if I continue typing it will be in the NEW font type, not the Comic Sans MS. I am trying to make it so if I continue typing after I have inserted the text via VBA code, it will retain my old formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple solution is to store all properties that you are going to change, and to reset them at the end:

```
Dim myText As String
Dim oldFont As String
Dim oldSize As Integer
Dim oldBold As Boolean

'Save old font
oldFont = Selection.Font.Name
oldSize = Selection.Font.Size
oldBold = Selection.Font.Bold

'Insert text with custom font
myText = "CUSTOM STRING"
Selection.Font.Name = "Comic Sans MS"
Selection.Font.Size = 26
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Selection.TypeText (myText)

'Revert font back to original
Selection.Font.Name = oldFont
Selection.Font.Bold = oldBold
Selection.Font.Size = oldSize
```

Answer (score 2):

The trick I find helpful when writing Word macros is simply to replicate what I'd be doing if I was using the Word GUI.  When I want to paste formatted text but keep my current format, I type a space, paste in the text before the space then delete the space.  As the space has my original format that's how I get it back.

So, doing this as a macro:

```
'Type a space
Selection.TypeText Text:=" "

'Move Cursor back one character
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1

'Insert text with custom font
myText = "CUSTOM STRING"
Selection.Font.Name = "Comic Sans MS"
Selection.Font.Size = 26
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Selection.TypeText (myText)

'Move Cursor forward one character
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1

'Delete the space
Selection.TypeBackspace
```

This will preserve any properties of the text you originally had.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite figure out exactly what you're trying to do there, but `Selection.TypeText` will collapse the selection down to the insertion point, so you effectively have no characters selected by the time you try to "revert the font". You either need to re-select the text, or use a `Range` object instead of the Selection to identify the text to be affected.

The reason that you get an error at the line:

```
Set Selection.Font = oldFont
```

...is because - unusually, and perversely - you should not use the `Set` keyword when assigning to the `Font` property. Rather than storing a reference to a `Font` object, the assignment simply applies the properties of the assigned font.

This is very confusing API design, made all the more confusing because you **do** need to use the `Set` keyword when *reading* the `Font` property, and because that **does** assign a reference to a `Font` object!

And that's the other reason why your code won't work - you're taking a reference to a `Font` object which you then modify, and your reference points to the same `Font` object that has now changed.

What you actually need to do is create a new `Font` object to store the original font details, as follows:

```
Set oldFont = Selection.Font.Duplicate
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. If I am typing text, I have a certain formatting that I'm typing in that is shown on the Home Tab (eg. Comic Sans Ms, Size 22, Bold). When I insert text with the macro, this changes the formatting that I'm typing with, so if I continue typing it will be in the NEW font type, not the Comic Sans MS. I'm trying to make it so if I continue typing after I have inserted the text via macro, it will retain my old formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The Selection.Font object is read only.

This means that there is no way to restore all the settings in one assignment. Since you are only changing a few properties the easiest solution is to save each individual value and restore them afterwards as stephan suggests.

I.e. Save properties:

```
oldFontName = Selection.Font.Name
oldFontSize = Selection.Font.Size
oldFontBold = Selection.Font.Bold
```

Do you stuff and then restore properties:

```
Selection.Font.Name = oldFontName
Selection.Font.Size = oldFontSize
Selection.Font.Bold = oldFontBold
```

Answer (score 0):

See, if this piece of code gives you enough hint.

`CopyFormat` picks up the existing formatting by moving left from current cursor.
`PasteFormat` applies it to a character & from there on, the original formatting (which was copied) comes into effect.

```
Selection.MoveLeft unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
Selection.EndKey Extend:=wdExtend

Selection.CopyFormat
Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdWord

'* New text and new formatting
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Selection.Font.Italic = True
Selection.Font.Size = 28
Selection.TypeText "hello world"

Selection.TypeText " "
Selection.MoveLeft unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.EndKey Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.PasteFormat


Selection.TypeText "original formatting here"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub No_Format()
'
' No_Format Macro
'
'
    Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteText
End Sub
```

this will allow you to paste the text and adopting the new formatting.